# How to use max in laravel local scope?

Tags: php, laravel, scope, subquery

I have 2 models `Temperature` and `TemperatureReading`

`Temperature` columns:

| name |
| --- |
| id |
| threshold |

---

`TemperatureReading` columns:

| name |
| --- |
| id |
| temperature_id |
| reading |

Using scope in `Temperature`, how can I return a collection of `Temperature` that match the follwoing query:

```
select *
from temperatures
where temperatures.threshold < 
(
   select max(reading) 
   from temperature_readings
   where temperature_readings.temperature_id = temperatures.id
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you basically want to retrieve all Temperature objects where a reading exists that exceeds the threshold. This doesn't really require the use of a max function.

I expect you already have a relation from your `Temperature` model to your `TemperatureReading` model? If not, it would be a great starting point:

```php
public function readings() {
    return $this->hasMany(TemperatureReading::class);
}
```

You can now use this relation to create the scope in your `Temperature` model:

```php
public function scopeExceededTreshold($query) 
{
    return $query->whereHas('readings', function($builder){
        $builder->whereRaw('temperatures.treshold < temperature_readings.reading');
    });
}
```

This will basically query the relation for any readings that exceed the threshold and only return the temperatures that meet that condition. You might want to tweak those names in the where clause depending on your actual table and column names.

Now, you could simply use the scope in your controller (or wherever) to only get those temperatures:

```php
Temperature::exceededTreshold()->get()
```

Just for your information, this is the generated SQL (which should provide the correct results):

```sql
select
    *
from
    temperatures
where
    exists (
        select
            *
        from
            temperature_readings
        where
            temperatures.id = temperature_readings.temperature_id
            and temperatures.treshold < temperature_readings.reading
    )
```